# JQuery advice needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page and I want to show some paragraphs after clicking a link, before that it should be hidden. So i wrote a simple JQuery code, but the problem is when I click the open link all the other hidden divs are also shown. My code is given below please advice how to solve the issue.

HTML

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="open_div">Read More</a>

<div class="expand_div">
<a href="#" class="close_div"><img src="images/close_button.gif" width="50" height="12" alt="Close" border="0" /></a>
<p>My hidden content goes here..</p>
</div>
</div>
```

and I want to repeat the above `<div>` block 7 times. So when I click the first div's Read more button the remaining 6 hidden divs are also showing!!!

JQuery

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.open_div').click(function(){
            $('.expand_div').show();
    });

    $('a.close_div').click(function(){
            $('.expand_div').hide();
    });

  });
</script>
```

how to solve this issue..?

any answers would be appreciated!

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this instead of your JQuery code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.open_div').click(function(){

          $(this).parent().find('.expand_div').show();
    });

    $('a.close_div').click(function(){
           $(this).parent().hide();
    });

  });
</script>
```

The problem with your code is that it's selecting ALL divs inside your page. and this is not what you want.
to solve this issue, this code is only limiting the scope of the action to the current link container, so the other divs will remain as is without any change.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the selectors will select all elements with that class. If you keep your structure like this, you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.open_div').click(function(){
          $(this).next().show();
    });

    $('a.close_div').click(function(){
          $(this).closest('.expand_div').hide();
    });
});
```

As the div is the next sibling of the open link, [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will select the div and show it. The close link on the other side is a descendant of the div. [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will find the closest ancestor that matches the selector.

Of course there are also other ways to select the elements.

See a [**working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gcCvc/).

Comment: Hi Felix thanks for quick reply but its not working, I want to show the '.expand_div' when click the 'a.open_div'  you did not mentioned in your above code. right..?

Comment: anyway I've to get going now, will reply in the morning Thanks again.

Comment: was going to push this... .closest() and .find() methods are awesome.  It's a good idea to just browse through the jQuery docs, they're pretty well written and not too hard to read straight through.  Although some of the new stuff in 1.5 not so much.

Comment: @Paul: Well, maybe your actual code is different from the one you posted. In your code `<div class="expand_div">` is the *next* element after the open link `<a href="#" class="open_div">Read More</a>`. So `$(this).next()` should select it. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gcCvc/

Answer (score 0):

In your `open` event you need to open the "next" element in the DOM:

```
$('a.open_div').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

In your `close` event you need to close the enclosing (parent) element:

```
$('a.close_div').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/raybellis/vZbp3/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all "expand_div" elements and showing them. You need to only select the appropriate elements as related to `this` element.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.open_div').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.expand_div').show();
    });

    $('a.close_div').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().siblings('.expand_div').hide();
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, for being classy and thanking everyone who tried to help. ;)